# strings with quotation marks in assembly

Tags: string, assembly, emu8086

I am using emu8086. I am trying to define a string like "I don't "listen" to radio".
When I use either of the following:

```
mystr db "I don't ""listen"" to radio"

mystr db 'I don"t "listen" to radio'
```

and try to print *mystr*, it prints either of the following, respectively:

> I don't ""listen"" to radio
>
> I don"t "listen" to radio

which is not what I want (I don't "listen" to radio). So, how can I define such a string?

Comment: `mystr db "I don't "listen" to radio"`

Comment: @MichaelPetch Does this work specifically in emu8086?

Comment: @SepRoland It works specifically in emu8086. I tested it out before putting it as a comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assemblers differ in how they treat embedded special characters like quotation marks, but the ASCII code comes to the rescue.

When a string you need to define has some *difficult* characters in it, you can always replace these by their ASCII codes. The double quotation mark has 34 for its ASCII code.

```
mystr db "I don't ", 34, "listen", 34, " to radio"
```

This will output:

> I don't "listen" to radio

Answer (score 3):

In NASM you can use single quotes for strings with embedded double quotes (and vise versa):

```
mystr db "I don't ", '"listen" to radio'
```